# R data manipulation for microdata

Tags: r, dataframe

I am very new to manipulating data by creating new variables within rows conditions, so please bear with me. 
My data looks something like this:

```
Unit  R Sex 
1000  1 1 
1000  2 2
1000  3 2
1000  3 2
1001  1 1
1001  2 1
1002  1 2
1003  1 1
1003  2 2
1003  4 2
```

where Unit is a household, R is the role of the household component (1 is head, 2 is spouse, 3 is children), sex is the corresponding sex.
I want to create a variable `newvar` that recodes Unit as 1 (0 otherwise) if a household has a same sex couple with children, if the household has children (R=3 exists) then recode as 1 if the sex of R=1 == sex of R= 2 within the same household/Unit. 
Any help on the subject is greatly appreciated!

Comment: In this example, is it all `0s` for newvar?  Also, I assume R==4 is also coding for children?, If that is the case, why there is no `3` for `1003` Unit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is:

```
 df1 <- unsplit(lapply(split(df, df$Unit),
                     function(x) {
                        indx <- x$Sex[x$R %in% 1:2]
                        if(length(unique(indx))==1 & length(indx)>1 & any(x$R==3)){
                        x$newvar <-1
                        } 
                      else x$newvar <-0 
                    x}),
                    df$Unit)

df1$newvar
# [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(Unit = c(1000L, 1000L, 1000L, 1000L, 1001L, 1001L, 
1002L, 1003L, 1003L, 1003L), R = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 4L), Sex = c(1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L)), .Names = c("Unit", 
"R", "Sex"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

Comment: Hi Akrun, it works but in the conditions you put something goes wrong and I get one also for the last Unit 1003 that "does not have kids" (4 is "other"), whereas I would need a 0 in `newvar`

Comment: @Ale Here, I am getting all `0s`.  Are you using the updated code?

Comment: Now it works with the new code, thanks! It looks quite complicated (with respect to the coding I am used to do). What does exactly `if(length(unique(indx))==1 & length(indx)>1` do?

Comment: @Ale First one checks the length of unique elements is 1 (ie. you wanted sex to be the same), and the second checks if there are more than one elements in sex.  Sometimes, there will be just only one element, so the length of unique(indx) will be 1 in that case.  The second condition make sure that those cases are accounted for.